# No puedo obtener el id de estos selects

Tags: javascript, html, api, datos

tengo un select que se trae los valores y los id de la API de provincias arg , como puedo obtener

el valor de esos id cuando cambien y poder usarlos para anidar a otro select y que cargen los

municipios de cada provincia correspondiente?

```
      const GetProvincias = async () => {
            try {
                let res = await axios.get('https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/provincias? 
                campos=id,nombre')
                json = await res.data;
               let opcion = `<option value="">Elige una provincia</option>`;
                 json.provincias.forEach(e => opcion += `<option id="${e.id}" 
                 value="${e.nombre}">${e.nombre}</option>`)
                 primary.innerHTML = opcion;
              } catch (err) {
             //console.log(err)
             let mensaje = err.response.statusText || "Ocurrio un error!"
             prov.innerHTML = `<b class="error">ERROR<b style="color:red">
          ${err.response.status}</b> ${mensaje}</b>`
         }
      }
```

como ven ya obtuve el id y se lo coloque a cada option, ahora como obtengo esos id para usarlos en otra peticion ?

Comment: Debes colocar un listener al select para el evento change. Cuando esto suceda tomas el value y haces las peticiones pertinentes para municipios

Comment: si perdon no mencione eso, obtengo el value, pero no puedo obtener el id del option seleccionado, y ahi es donde me pierdo, no se me ocurre como o si estoy haciendo algo mal

Comment: Es que en el `value` del `option` deberias poner el `id`, no el `nombre` de la provincia

Comment: me funciono, muchas gracias.